# A view that resides in a sub folder cannot use local bootstrap file in a express app

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to learn using express to make web app but am facing a problem that i need to solve. I am using local bootstrap files in the project which resides in public folder. The issue is add.handlebars view which resides within ideas folder in views directory, is unable to use local boostrap files but other views which are in the root of views folder are able to use bootstrap files

[Project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHSHs.png)

```
const express = require('express')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/vidjot', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('MongoDb connected')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

require('./models/Idea')
const Idea = mongoose.model('ideas')

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}))
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Home | Vidjot'
    })
})

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about', {
        title: "About | Vidjot"
    })
})

app.get("/ideas/add", (req, res) => {
    res.render('ideas/add')
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started at port ${port}`)
})
```

```html
main.handlebars view


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> _navbar}}
    <div class="container">
        {{{body}}}
    </div>
    <script src="jquery/jquery4.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="popper/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Home page is able to load bootstrap files successfully
[home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtCot.png)

But ideas/add page it cannot load bootstarp files
[ideas/add page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNQMu.png)

When i look at it source code, links towards bootstrap files appears to add the word ideas before the path to bootstrap files
[ideas/add view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq0S4.png)

Comment: Use absolute paths instead of relative paths for static assets. Change this `"bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"` to `"/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Comment: Thanks... Tried it and worked perfect